# Designing Sound Effects For Digital UI

Tags: sound-design, synthesis, digital, digital-technology

I'm trying to get better sound design and I wanted to tackle the area of digital sounds for UI that you'd see in a sci-fi thriller or something like that. Something like the sounds at the beginning of this [YouTube clip](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HkPW3KavBq4). How do you approach these sounds using synthesis? Side note: I'm using Logic Pro X with Serum, but the tools probably aren't too important. Thanks in advance!